# SP13 - Con app How to set string to DateTime Field

Tags: sharepoint-server, date-time

I want to to set string to DateTime field programatically with C# Object model

**This is my code:**

```
string date = "11.13.1992 г.";

//DateOfRegist(Date Time)
addItem["DateOfRegist"] = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd.MM.yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Error is:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime` is a clear error that informs you the provided string is not a valid to be parsed to a date value.

In your case, I think it's a `Russia` date that its Date format should be **DMY** not **MDY** as mentioned at [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

So to convert this string properly, your code should look like

```
string date = "13.11.1992 г.";
addItem["DateOfRegist"] = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU")).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Meanwhile, if you need to convert the string to **DMY** format, you should remove   **г.** from your string and use `en-US` as the following:

```
string date = "11.13.1992";
addItem["DateOfRegist"] = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```